# How to optimize a T-SQL query that fetches from one or the other of two tables

Tags: t-sql, query-optimization, sql-server-2014

There are two identical tables. A dynamic parameter will determine which of the two tables to get data from. The approach I took is to union results from both tables and add a predicate to each subquery to filter on the parameter passed in (please see below). This has produced an estimated execution plan that reads both tables and then applies the filter. Is there a way to optimize the query without using a condition (like IF) so that only the appropriate table is queried?

```
create table Flip (ID uniqueidentifier)
create table Flop (ID uniqueidentifier)
```

The query

```
declare @useFlip bit
select * from Flip where @useFlip=1
union
select * from Flop where @useFlip<>1
```

Execution plan

[image]

Comment: Btw, `union all` instead of `union` presumably could remove that 63% Sort step

Comment: From the comments on the answer, it seems we don't have the full picture here (as you've now informed me that you're using an iTVF, which you don't detail above). Seems we need to be told the real problem you're trying to solve, as otherwise this could likely be an XY Problem if usung `UNION ALL` doesn't help things.

Comment: If the function is inlined and the resultant query has the `recompile` query hint then the query optimizer should Do The Right Thing℠. Unfortunately the iTVF can't force the consuming query to recompile.

Answer (score 0):

I would personally move to a dynamic statement or `IF...ELSE` logic. As you're only ever going to query one table, it makes more sense to create a plan that's relevant.

Dynamic approach:

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);

SET @SQL = N'SELECT * FROM ' + QUOTENAME(CASE @UseFlip WHEN 1 THEN N'Flip' ELSE N'Flop' END) + N';';
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
```

`IF...ELSE` Approach:

```
IF @UseFlip = 1
    SELECT * FROM Flip;
ELSE
    SELECT * FROM Flop;
```

*Edit:* The above above been completely invalidated, as the OP commented below this answer to advise they are using an inline table-value function (this information is not in the question at this time). Neither of these statements can be used in an iTVF.

Comment: Hmm I am trying to avoid IF...ELSE as I like to make the query part of an inline table valued function.

Comment: Why didn't you mention that in the question @Sumith ? That completely invalidates my answer...

Comment: It is there in the question. I said I want to avoid condition (like IF).

Comment: *"I want to not use an `IF`"* does not translate to "I am using an iTVF, therefore everything must be within a single statement." @Sumith .

Comment: But I don't want to use an IF...ELSE. Moreover when I first typed the question it had the create function definition and it seems a big page of question. So I trimmed it down to just the specific bit. Now, about the subject, is there a different way to express the semantics of the query so that both tables aren't scanned? Or is there a way to educate SQL to use one plan for @useFilp=1 and another plan when @useFlip=0?

Comment: *"express the semantics of the query so that both tables aren't scanned?"* not with an iTVF, no.